# R opening socket connection server and starting socket connection client from one script

Tags: r, sockets, multiple-instances

I have an R Code from server side:

```
socket.reader <- function(host="localhost", port=6011, time_freq){
  shell(paste("C:/Users/Stefan/source/repos/Quick-Check/Debug/Quick-Check.exe","COM3","127.0.0.1",port,time_freq))
  con <- socketConnection("localhost", port,server=TRUE, open="r+")
  txt <- readLines(con)
  close(con)
  return(txt)
}

observeEvent(input$socket_reader, {
 input<-socket.reader(time_freq=input$Samp_Freq*60)
 #tosave<-ts(as.numeric(input), frequency=200)
 write.csv(input,"C:/Users/Stefan/Documents/app/data/samplerun")
})
```

It is supposed to start socket server, then execute the .exe and read in all that the .exe sents to the server(exe is from cpp measuring some device).
Problem is, as soon as the socket connection opens on server side, the r-process seems to be blocked and does not evaluate the .exe until the socket is closed by timeout again. I tried to put the .exe before the server is opened and put a 3 second delay within the .exe, but it seems, that the .exe starts, gets a delay, proceeds to evaluate the r-server socket connection, which again produces a hold until timeout.

Does anyone have an idea, how to start another process from within R so that both will be evaluated at the same time or to unhold the R instance while the socket connection is opened?
Best Wishes

Comment: You could use the future package for this.

Comment: I have a feeling that this might work and tried around alot, what do you think the synthax should be like, for now I tried:
`plan(multisession)


con %<-% {socketConnection_server}
born %<-%{socketConnection_client}
con
born
write.csv(readLines(con,5),"C:/samplerun")`

but I am only getting character(0) as response within the csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `wait = FALSE` works on your system, you can specify that option whan starting the socket server:

```
system2("nc", "-l -p 6011 -c /bin/cat", wait = FALSE)

con <- socketConnection(host="localhost", port = 6011, blocking=TRUE,
                        server=FALSE, open="r+")
write_resp <- writeLines("Hello, world!", con)
server_resp <- readLines(con, 1)
print(paste("Server response:  ", server_resp))
close(con)
```

Alternatively you can use the `future` package:

```
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

server %<-% {
    system2("nc", "-l -p 6011 -c /bin/cat")
}

con <- socketConnection(host="localhost", port = 6011, blocking=TRUE,
                        server=FALSE, open="r+")
write_resp <- writeLines("Hello, world!", con)
server_resp <- readLines(con, 1)
print(paste("Server response:  ", server_resp))
close(con)
```

Here only the `server` is declared as a future, whereas the client code is executed within the parent session.

Note: the `nc` command just opens a simple echo server on port `6011`.

Comment: Got it working with future, had to put down a batch script thought which gets created each time the shell is going to be started... seems to be some bug with R

Comment: @Nuke. Great that is working for you. consider adding your own answer if you think your solution could be useful to others.